# WPF window position is not working properly on dual monitor

Tags: c#, wpf

I have developed WPF application and I'm running it on a dual monitor system, and I want to open my startup window on the main monitor.
I have used the following code to setup position.

```
var desktopWorkingArea = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea;

this.Left = desktopWorkingArea.Right - this.Width;

this.Top = desktopWorkingArea.Bottom - this.Height;
```

But the problem is that Main window on some machine is opening at proper position but on some it is not.
The resolution of all machines are same.

Comment: why didn't you use `Left = desktopWorkingArea.Left` and `Top = desktopWorkingArea.Top` ? the window is not maximized initially and you wanted to dock to right and top?

Comment: You problem is probably caused because some machines have their two monitor plugs mixed up at the back of the PC and have fixed the issue in the *Windows Screen Resolution* window, while others have the main monitor correctly plugged into the main input on the graphics card.